# syntax highlighting for template embeded in to JSON

Tags: sublimetext2

I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to Sublime Text 2 having recently switched from KomodoEdit.
I'm trying to setup syntax highlighting for a template string that gets embedded into a JSON request. Here are a couple example lines:

```
{
"shipment_number": "{%% prop : parent-clip : SHIPMENT_NUMBER %%}",
"product_code": {%% prop : parent-clip : PCNum %%}
}
```

the part I want highlight is the `{%% property-type : path-type : property-path %%}` part and highlight the {%% and the 3 text pieces individually. So I've read a lot of stuff on Sublime and Textmate and many example git but I'm still not grocking this stuff. Could someone point me in the right direction? here is what put together so far

```
{ "name": "JSON+CloudTest ISSE",
  "scopeName": "source.isse",
  "fileTypes": ["json"], 
  "patterns": [
      { "name": "keyword.tag.isse",
      "comment": "based on example at http://gerd.knops.org/?p=9",
      "include" : "source.json",
        "begin": "{%%",
      "match": "\\b([^:]+)\\b", 
      "captures" : {
        "1" : {"name" : "storage.type.isse"},
        "2" : {"name" : "storage.modifier.isse"},
        "3" : {"name" : "storage.type.variable.isse"}
      },
        "end": "%%}",
   ],
  "uuid": "4e9dce7e-287e-4ec0-b13f-bfed23b44982"
}
```

when I try to build this the tmlanguage file is a zero byte file. why?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mismatched curly braces (there should be a curly brace after `"end": "%%}",` though the comma should be removed first). I fixed it and ran it through a json to plist converter.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>fileTypes</key>
    <array>
        <string>json</string>
    </array>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>JSON+CloudTest ISSE</string>
    <key>patterns</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>begin</key>
            <string>{%%</string>
            <key>captures</key>
            <dict>
                <key>1</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>storage.type.isse</string>
                </dict>
                <key>2</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>storage.modifier.isse</string>
                </dict>
                <key>3</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>storage.type.variable.isse</string>
                </dict>
            </dict>
            <key>comment</key>
            <string>based on example at http://gerd.knops.org/?p=9</string>
            <key>end</key>
            <string>%%}</string>
            <key>include</key>
            <string>source.json</string>
            <key>match</key>
            <string>\b([^:]+)\b</string>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>keyword.tag.isse</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>scopeName</key>
    <string>source.isse</string>
    <key>uuid</key>
    <string>4e9dce7e-287e-4ec0-b13f-bfed23b44982</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: @anotherNerdHere I'll let skuroda edit his post if he wants, but he probably used the [`PlistJsonConverter`](https://github.com/facelessuser/PlistJsonConverter) plugin for ST2. I highly recommend it if you'll be doing any work with `.tmLanguage` or `.tmTheme` files.

Comment: @skuroda thanks for the help the resulting file. I really appreciate it. now I have to create the highlighting part.

Comment: @MattDMo Thanks for the tip and link. SublimeText2 is really pretty amazing but figuring out how to do this kinda stuff ins't the easiest at least for me so any tips are much appreciated.

Comment: @skuroda oops that should have read thanks for the help AND the resulting file.

Comment: @MattDMo Yup was just being lazy. It's in your comment now so I won't bother reposting it.